# Which scenarios to use .NET Concurrent Collections effectively?

Tags: .net, f#, parallelism

I am investigating how to introduce parallelism into an application to improve performance. In particular, I am looking at parallel for loops and their variants and my initial experiments show significant overhead to using collections from the `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace.

## Typical scenario

Want to iterate over a collection in Parallel, perform some computations per iteration and then route/add the results into an appropriate collection depending on the details of the iteration.

[If you don't use the Concurrent Collections you get errors due to the usual multi-threading & synchronization issues so you appear to be forced into using the Concurrent collections.]

Unfortunately my tests mostly/often show that the single-threaded simple solutions perform faster due to the overhead of using the Concurrent Collections - is this to be expected?

## Tentative Conclusions

You would need to be doing a "very large" piece of work **per iteration** for the Concurrent Collections to perform better than a single threaded solution?

## Code Example

As per requests in the comments:

```fsharp
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.Collections.Concurrent
open FSharp.Collections.ParallelSeq

type Data = {
    Name:string
    mutable Age:int
    Description:string
}

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

    let xs = ResizeArray<Data>()
    let n = 1000000

    let rand = System.Random()

    // create some random data
    for i in 0..n do
        let f1 = rand.NextDouble()
        let f2 = rand.NextDouble()
        let data = {Name = "My Name" + f1.ToString() + f2.ToString(); Age = 38; Description = "Happy"}
        xs.Add(data)

    // single-threaded example
    let normalCollection = Dictionary<string,Data>()
    let stopWatch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()
    stopWatch.Start()
    xs |> Seq.iter (fun x -> 
        x.Age <- x.Age + rand.Next()
        normalCollection.[x.Name] <- x
        )
    stopWatch.Stop()
    printfn "Single Threaded: %A" stopWatch.Elapsed

    System.GC.Collect(2)

    // single-threaded + concurrent Collection example
    let concurrentCollection = ConcurrentDictionary<string,Data>()
    let stopWatch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()
    stopWatch.Start()
    xs |> Seq.iter (fun x -> 
        x.Age <- x.Age + rand.Next()
        concurrentCollection.[x.Name] <- x
        )
    stopWatch.Stop()
    printfn "Single Threaded + Concurrent Collection: %A" stopWatch.Elapsed

    concurrentCollection.Clear()

    System.GC.Collect(2)

    // multi-threaded example
    let concurrentCollection = ConcurrentDictionary<string,Data>()
    let stopWatch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()
    stopWatch.Start()
    xs |> PSeq.iter (fun x -> 
        x.Age <- x.Age + rand.Next()
        concurrentCollection.[x.Name] <- x
        )
    stopWatch.Stop()
    printfn "Multi-Threaded: %A" stopWatch.Elapsed

    // Functional Style
    normalCollection.Clear()
    System.GC.Collect(2)
    let stopWatch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()
    stopWatch.Start()
    let ys = 
        xs 
        |> PSeq.map (fun x -> {x with Age = x.Age + rand.Next()} )
        |> Seq.iter (fun x -> normalCollection.[x.Name] <- x)
    stopWatch.Stop()
    printfn "Functional Style: %A" stopWatch.Elapsed

    printfn "%A" argv
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

## Timing

Consistent over multiple runs...

**n = 10,000 (small data set)**

> Single Threaded: 00:00:00.0048328
>
> Single Threaded + Concurrent Collection: 00:00:00.0053433
>
> Multi-Threaded: 00:00:00.0197919
>
> Functional Style: 00:00:00.0073613

**n = 10,000,000 (large data set)**

> Single Threaded: 00:00:04.0683213
>
> Single Threaded + Concurrent Collection: 00:00:13.6469918
>
> Multi-Threaded: 00:00:10.9768615
>
> Functional Style: 00:00:04.6633076

Comment: You may want to read this https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19222  even though it is C#/VB it might help.  Without knowing the particulars it is difficult to comment.

Comment: +1 Every time I've tried to use concurrent collections, I've found using `lock` with a normal collection both faster (marginally) and less awkward.

Comment: Can you show a non-trivial example in which you see this effect? Whereas the concurrent collections *do* have some overhead, I've used them successfully to get great performance increases in some of my programs. Are you sure it's the collections and not something else that's causing your slowdown?

Comment: @JimMischel I have posted some example code. Naturally I've had to trivialize it as much as possible for space reasons but it still illustrates the pattern I am trying to parallelize; namely: iterate in parallel and build up a result set.

Comment: I think your code is missing some of the point of functional programming. Have you tried using `.map` instead of `.iter` and converting the sequence to a collection at the end? An immutable collection even (like `Map<TKey,TValue>`)?

Comment: You're not measuring the overhead of the concurrent collection. To do that, you'd replace `normalCollection` with `concurrentCollection`, and run it single-threaded. What you're seeing is *contention*. And that occurs because a huge percentage of the running time in your trivial example is spent in the collection, with multiple threads contending for a single shared resource (or, if `ConcurrentDictionary` is lock-free, retrying failed optimistic updates). You're not going to see any performance improvement unless you do some non-trivial processing that doesn't involve the collection.

Comment: @JimMischel You are right - I was measuring the effect of the concurrent collection incorrectly - this has been remedied above BUT the result is to further highlight the relatively poorer performance of the Concurrent Collection! This would not be due to locking as all happening on a single thread.

Comment: @KaseySpeakman I have added a `functionally styled` example to the above but the conclusion is similar to other examples I have seen - this approach does not compete with the vanilla single-threaded solution. PS: working with Map<_,_> in F# is never performant - I always just use Dictionary instead.

Comment: @Sam, Your functionally styled example is still fraught with side effects (not actually functional). Try `xs |> PSeq.map (fun x -> (x.Name, {x with Age = x.Age + rand.Next()}) ) |> dict`. The your `ys` would be a new dictionary with updated age.

Comment: @KaseySpeakman I realize it's not great functional style but I find when I push for performance my style suffers. That said, not sure about the last pipe in your code above "|> dict" ? Is this a library I am missing or was that a shorthand for something?

Comment: @Sam, It's a [built-in F# operator, dict](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353774.aspx). It takes a sequence of `'key * 'value` and converts it to a `IDictionary<'key, 'value>`

Comment: Okay, so now you know that `ConcurrentCollection` is approximately 33% as fast as your normal collection in single-threaded mode. It's not surprising or even unexpected that `ConcurrentCollection` is slower than a  data structure that doesn't support concurrent modification by multiple threads. Unless your real-world problem involves much more per-item processing, then you should do this single threaded, find a more efficient concurrent data structure (probably difficult), or find a different multithreading model (like a per-thread dictionary that you merge when all items are processed).

Answer (score 6):

You're missing the point. The concurrent collections aren't there for performance so much. They're there so you don't need to try and do all the locking around a dictionary/queue yourself, since doing so is error prone and tedious. *(And they're really there so you don't need to try and implement lockless dictionaries/queues yourself)*

Using them effectively is as simple as "hey, I have a queue/dictionary/etc, and it needs to be accessed concurrently. Instead of reinventing the wheel, I will use these pre-built classes". You don't use them to introduce concurrency, you introduce concurrency because you need to, and these things help.

Comment: You don't need to try to implement a threadsafe dictionary anyway when `lock` exists. Besides, I rarely find I need to only update a concurrent collection and nothing else. There is usually some other variable, flag, etc that needs updating when the collection is updated. At that point using lock with a normal collection is much less awkward than the lockless collection semantics (AddOrUpdate, etc).

Comment: @KaseySpeakman - Sorry, I meant to lump that in with the "implement threadsafe". I will clarify.

Answer (score 1):

What you are measuring is the speed of adding a fixed set key-value pairs to a `Dictionary` in the reduce part of a map-reduce operation.

The `ConcurrentDictionary` is meant for a more general use-case: concurrent readers+writers, no coordination between any of the participants, writes to the same keys, reads to the same keys. There is a performance cost to each of those features, so it is no surprise the `ConcurrentDictionary` isn't competitive in your benchmark.

Two ways to explore from here could be:

1. How to implement a `Dictionary` that gains from multiple threads in your benchmark?
2. What is a realistic benchmark that requires the features `ConcurrentDictionary` provides and how does it's performance compare in that case?

Answer (score 1):

> You would need to be doing a "very large" piece of work per iteration for the Concurrent Collections to perform better than a single threaded solution?

You could say that, as long as "very large" means something like "operation that takes more than an order of magnitude longer than a concurrent collection operation". But since concurrent collection operations are still pretty fast, your "very large" is actually not large at all.

Concurrent collections are not really meant to compete with standard collections, instead they compete with *locking*, which is what you would normally do when you wanted to modify the same collection from multiple threads. And compared with locking, concurrent collections are more efficient (and also easier to use correctly).

But parallelization or concurrent collections are not a silver bullet, they won't make code that can't be parallelized well magically faster.

---

There are also some issues with your benchmark, which may affect the results:

1. `Random` is not thread-safe, you shouldn't use it from multiple threads.
2. You're reusing the same collection in subsequent tests. That's problematic, because it means only the first measurement includes resizing the collection.
3. Your "Functional style" test generates lots of garbage that likely won't be collected by the end of the test. For that reason, I prefer to call `GC.Collect()` *before* stopping the stopwatch. This way, code that generates lots of garbage is properly penalized.